# How to loop through LI items in UL, get specific attributes, and pass them via $.ajax data

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my HTML code:

```
<ul id="gallery">
    <li id="attachment-32" class="featured"><a href="..." title=""><img src="..." alt="" /></a></li>
    <li id="attachment-34"><a href="..." title=""><img src="..." alt="" /></a></li>
    <li id="attachment-38"><a href="..." title=""><img src="..." alt="" /></a></li>
    <li id="attachment-64"><a href="..." title=""><img src="..." alt="" /></a></li>
    <li id="attachment-75"><a href="..." title=""><img src="..." alt="" /></a></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Here is my sample ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/upload.php',
        type: 'POST',
    data: { ... },
        success: function(data){
        }
});
```

Here is what I want to achieve.

1. How to get the attachment number in ID attribute for every LI inside the gallery UL only when an ID attr is there and pass them via ajax data in this way: `{ attached : '32,34,38,64,75' }` if there is a better way of doing this let me know I want to pass the list items which contain attachments to process. **I want to avoid LI items which are empty, do not include id attr.**
2. How to get the list item LI which has class of featured e.g. { featured_img : .. } and pass the attachment ID number if featured LI exists, and if none of list items is featured pass featured_img with 0. So i know how to process it via php in the request.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) for that:

```
var ids = $("#gallery li").map(function () {
    return this.id.split("-")[1];
}).get().join(",");
```

...

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/upload.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { ids: ids },
    success: function(data) {

    }
});
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/knav4/)

Comment: Worked perfectly. How can I get the LI which has class of "featured" if it exists? return 0 if none exist, or ID attr if it exists.

Comment: Modify the selector to only grab `.featured` LIs? `$("#gallery li.featured").map(`

Comment: Or if you want *exactly what you just described* (which seems a little pointless to me, that is, actually filling up the string with zeros), you can do this: http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/knav4/5/

Comment: It is pointless as you say. That does the job perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this, May be help you.

```
var val = new Array();
$('#gallery li').each(function(){
    val.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
document.write(val);
```

Example to implement.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/upload.php',
        type: 'POST',
    data: { attached : val },
        success: function(data){
        }
});
```

Hope this help you.